# Easiest way to get Enum in to Key Value pair

Tags: java, enums

I have defined my Enums like this.

```
public enum UserType {

    RESELLER("Reseller"),

    SERVICE_MANAGER("Manager"),

    HOST("Host");

    private String name;

    private UserType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

What should be the easiest way to get a key-value pair form the enum values?

The output map i want to create should be like this

```
key   = Enum(example:- HOST)
value = Host
```

The map I want do define is

```
Map<String, String> constansts = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Ans: What I Did

I have created a Generic Method to access any enum and change values from that to a Map. I got this IDEA, form a code fragment found at here in any other thread.

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Map<String, String> getConstantMap(
        Class<T> klass) {

    Map<String, String> vals = new HashMap<String, String>(0);

    try {
        Method m = klass.getMethod("values", null);
        Object obj = m.invoke(null, null);

        for (Enum<T> enumval : (Enum<T>[]) obj) {
            vals.put(enumval.name(), enumval.toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // shouldn't happen...
    }

    return vals;
}
```

Now, After this all I have to do is call this method with all the enum constructs and i am Done.

One More thing

To get This done i have to orverride the toString Method like this

```
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you want the enum or the string to be the key?

Comment: instead of all that reflection stuff, you can just do `klass.getEnumConstants()`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Provided you need to map from the textual values to the enum instances:

```
Map<String, UserType> map = new HashMap<String, UserType>();
map.put(RESELLER.getName(), RESELLER);
map.put(SERVICE_MANAGER.getName(), SERVICE_MANAGER);
map.put(HOST.getName(), HOST);
```

or a more generic approach:

```
for (UserType userType : UserType.values()) {
    map.put(userType.getName(), userType);
}
```

Comment: This is the very HARD way indeed. Don't there exists any thing out of box? There must be something........

Comment: @vijay.shad see my update. If you give more details in your question, you increase the chances of getting exactly what you are looking for :-)

Comment: There is no easier way given to you by Java... sorry

Comment: How is a loop containing one line (three lines total including the closing brace if you use them) the "very HARD way indeed"?

Comment: The point is: I may need to come back to code and update the map; every time a user type is added in the enum. I have used enum to define my constants and I want to access then as a Map.

Comment: @vijay: **why** do you need it as a Map? Are you aware of the `valueOf()` method provided by all enums? What do you want to solve that's not solved by `UserType.valueOf(someString).getName()`?

Comment: For clarification: Vijay's first comment is about an earlier version of my answer, which did not yet contain the second solution with the loop. I believe the latter version satisfies his requirement.

Answer (score 17):

Java 8 way:

```
Arrays.stream(UserType.values())
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserType::getName, Function.identity()))
```

Understandably store it in a variable :)

Answer (score 14):

You could use the values() method on the enum, giving you all possible combinations, and put that in a map using the iterator.

```
Map<String, UserType> map = new HashMap<String, UserType>();
for (UserType userType : UserType.values()) {
    map.put(userType.name(), userType);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the eaiest method for using an Enum as a key in a map is using an EnumMap http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use EnumMap which is a Map implementation that exclusively takes Enum as its keys.

```
EnumMap<UserType, String> activityMap = new EnumMap<>(UserType.class);
```

> However, EnumMap requires the key type in the constructor.

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-enum-map

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 stream api and assignment immediately to the desired structure:

```
HashMap<String, UserType> collect = Arrays.stream(UserType.values())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            UserType::getName,
            Function.identity(),
            (prev, next) -> next, HashMap::new)
    );
```